# Use fse.readFile() inside .map()

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, fs

I am trying to read the contents of several files in Node.js using promises. Since the standard `fs` module does not provide a sufficient promise interface, I decided to use [`fs-extra`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) instead which provides pretty much the same functions as the default `fs` module with an additional promise interface.

Reading the contents of a single file as shown below works as desired and logs the file's contents to the console:

```
const fse = require('fs-extra')

const filePath = './foo.txt'


fse.readFile(filePath, 'utf8')
    .then(filecontents => {
        return filecontents
    })
    .then(filecontents => {
        console.log(filecontents)
    })
```

However, I need to handle several files inside a given directory. To do this I need to implement the following steps:

1. get an array of all files inside the directory using `fse.readdir()` - *done*
2. join filenames and directory name to get a kind of a base file path using `path.join` with `.map()` to avoid iterating over the array - *done*
3. read file contents using `fse.readFile()` inside another `.map()`

These three steps are implemented as follows:

```
const fse = require('fs-extra');
const path = require('path');

const mailDirectory = './mails'


fse.readdir(mailDirectory)
    .then(filenames => {
        return filenames.map(filename => path.join(mailDirectory, filename))
    })
    .then(filepaths => {
        // console.log(filepaths)
        return filepaths
            .map(filepath => fse.readFile(filepath).then(filecontents => {
                return filecontents
            }))
    })
    .then(mailcontents => {
        console.log(mailcontents)
    })
```

As stated above, steps 1 and 2 are working quite nice. However, I am unable to read the file contents using `fse.readFile()` inside the last `.map()` which results in an

```
[ Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> } ]
```

output indicating that the promise is not resolved, yet. I assume that this unresolved promise is the promise returned by the `fse.readFile()` function. However I am unable to resolve it properly since a comparable approach in my very first snippet works like a charm.

How could I solve this issue? Where does it exactly come from since I am a newbie in the field of JS and especially in the field of Node.js?

Comment: You have an Array of Promises.  Why not wait on them using `Promise.all()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an Array of Promises.  You should wait on them using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
const fse = require('fs-extra');
const path = require('path');

const mailDirectory = './mails'


fse.readdir(mailDirectory)
    .then(filenames => {
        return filenames.map(filename => path.join(mailDirectory, filename))
    })
    .then(filepaths => {
        // console.log(filepaths)
        return filepaths
            .map(filepath => fse.readFile(filepath).then(filecontents => {
                return filecontents
            }))
    })
    // Promise.all consumes an array of promises, and returns a 
    // new promise that will resolve to an array of concrete "answers"
    .then(mailcontents => Promise.all(mailcontents))
    .then(realcontents => {
        console.log(realcontents)
    });
```

---

Also, if you don't want to have to have an additional dependency on `fs-extra` you can use node 8's new [`util.promisify()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to make `fs` follow a Promise oriented API.

Comment: Assuming `console.log(mailcontents)` is a typo and should be `console.log(realcontents)`

Comment: @albert Yes, my bad.  Fixed